# How to translate SQL into SQLAlchemy? (Shaping output model differently from the DB model)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQL request that is giving me the result I want, but I can't succeed to make it work in SQLAlchemy.

#### DB Models

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    image = db.Column(db.String(255))
    brand = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
    prices = relationship("ArticlePrice", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class ArticlePrice(db.Model):
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("article.id"), primary_key=True)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"), primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    location = relationship('Location')
```

#### SQL request (working)

I want to return *all* articles information that are located in the given location and active in this location. Plus its `price`, and *only* the price of this location.

```
SELECT a.*, ap.price
FROM article a
INNER JOIN article_prices ap ON a.id = ap.article_id
WHERE ap.location_id = 1
AND ap.active = true
```

#### SQLAlchemy, using Flask (*not* working)

```
@namespace.route('/location/<location_id>')
class ArticleLocatedAPI():
    @namespace.marshal_list_with(article, envelope='articles')
    def get(self, location_id):
        return Article.query.filter(Article.prices.any(active=True, location_id=location_id)).all()
```

#### Output model

As you can see, I want the `price` of the located articles not the `relationship` that would return the array of prices.

```
article = namespace.model('Article', {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'title': fields.String,
    'description': fields.String,
    'image': fields.String,
    'brand': fields.String,
    'price': fields.Float,
    'category_id': fields.Integer
})
```

#### Problem

The code above is giving me the right articles. The problem is that it is returning me the `relationship`, which is giving me an array of prices. I want to return the `price` of the located article. How am I supposed to write that in SQLAlchemy?

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the `Article.prices` collection to a subset of all prices by using an explicit [`join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) combined with [`contains_eager()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) option, as is explained in ["Using contains_eager() to load a custom-filtered collection result"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result):

```
return Article.query.\
    join(Article.prices).\
    filter_by(active=True, location_id=location_id).\
    options(db.contains_eager(Article.prices).load_only("price")).\
    all()
```

[`filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) extracts its keyword arguments from either the primary entity of the [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query), or the target entity of the last join, which is `ArticlePrice` in this case. Using [`load_only()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only) allows you to limit the set of attributes to load from `ArticlePrice`. The SQL produced is pretty much identical to your original, save for the primary keys of `ArticlePrice` – [you're using an ORM after all](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key):

```
SELECT article_price.article_id AS article_price_article_id, article_price.location_id AS article_price_location_id, article_price.price AS article_price_price, article.id AS article_id, article.title AS article_title, article.description AS article_description, article.image AS article_image, article.brand AS article_brand, article.category_id AS article_category_id 
FROM article JOIN article_price ON article.id = article_price.article_id 
WHERE article_price.active = 1 AND article_price.location_id = ?
```

To [rename](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/marshalling.html#renaming-attributes) and unpack the collection of prices to a scalar pass the `attribute=` keyword argument to field constructor:

```
article = namespace.model('Article', {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'title': fields.String,
    'description': fields.String,
    'image': fields.String,
    'brand': fields.String,
    'price': fields.Float(attribute=lambda a: a.prices[0].price),
    'category_id': fields.Integer
})
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! <3 I am just gonna have to dig more into `options(db.contains_eager(Article.prices).load_only("price"))`. I think that's the magical part I don't understand ^^

Comment: If you'd want to get *really* creative, you could create a separate "LocationAwareArticle" [mapping against a join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables) between `Article` and `ArticlePrice`, and `Location` if need be.